# How to put the Total at the top on AG GRID

Tags: ag-grid

I would want to displace the row "Total" on AG GRID at the top of my table. How do I do that, please ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share some images, codes and what you have tried, so that your question can be properly understood.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what did you mean by "Total" but these two document can solve your problem.

[row-pinning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-pinning/)

[status-bar](http://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/status-bar/)